# A solution on getting a specific amount of results from a SQL expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem getting the specific amount of results that I want from a specific SQL expression. Could someone help me with the correct way of limiting the result that I will get from this expression:

```
SELECT 
    bill.bill_id, bill.total_price, bill.sell_time, 
    bill.user_id, login.username AS Expr1
FROM 
    bill 
INNER JOIN
    login ON bill.user_id = login.user_id;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add `FETCH FIRST <n> ROWS ONLY`, `LIMIT <n>`, or `TOP <n>`, depending on the database you are using.

Comment: That really does depend on what rdbms you are using. for access / ms sql it's `select top n`. for mysql it's `select ..... limit n`

Comment: I am using microsoft sql server. What is the best way i could write this expression?

Comment: Remember - with no `ORDER BY` specified, you might get a different(ly ordered) result set every time you run the query.

Comment: thank you guys this work for me:
`SELECT top 4 bill.bill_id, bill.total_price, bill.sell_time, bill.user_id, login.username AS Expr1 FROM bill INNER JOIN login ON bill.user_id = login.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Oracle,

Try

```
Select *  
from
    (SELECT 
         rownum rn, bill.bill_id, bill.total_price, bill.sell_time, 
         bill.user_id, login.username AS Expr1
     FROM bill 
     INNER JOIN login ON bill.user_id = login.user_id)
Where rn <= 100;
```

It will get first 100 rows

For sql server

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT bill.bill_id, bill.total_price, bill.sell_time,  bill.user_id, login.username AS Expr1 ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY   bill.bill_id) as rn FROM bill  INNER JOIN login ON bill.user_id = login.user_id)
Where rn <= 100;
```

If you have sql server 12

```
SELECT  bill.bill_id, bill.total_price, bill.sell_time, bill.user_id, login.username AS Expr1 FROM bill INNER JOIN login ON bill.user_id =login.user_id ORDER BY bill.bill_id OFFSET  100 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work! I don't mention before but i am using it on vb.net with microsoft sql server

Comment: Please try queries given for sql server

Comment: Why not just "SELECT TOP 100 ..."?